# Editing responsive html codes

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, css

I own a website called [www.elitemaths.com.au](http://www.elitemaths.com.au) that is joomla based.

Because I am new to joomla I need to ask you two things that may be basic for you guys.

First, how do I go about changing the texts on my main page? (circled). I have looked in the css template and also the articles embedded into the main page. However, the article part of the main page seems to start from half way down the main page.
[image: screenshot1]

Second question is, how do I change/remove the phone number in the bottom menu bar? Is this part of the footer? Something I can change in the joomla control panel?

[image: screenshot2]

I appreciate your help.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two content items you wish to update look like they are modules and these can be updated via Extensions -> Modules in the back-end of your website.

If there is a long list of enabled modules, you can narrow down the search by going to Extensions -> Templates -> Options, temporarily setting Preview Module Positions = "Enabled" and browsing to www.elitemaths.com.au/index.php?tp=1 to see what module positions these items are published to.

Looking at the source code, the header module seems to have a module ID of 117 and the footer module seems to have a module ID of 92.

You might also be able to log in to the front-end of the website via www.elitemaths.com.au/index.php?option=com_users&view=login and click on the edit icon associated with each of these modules to edit them directly, assuming your website is set up to allow editing of modules from the front-end.